# If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is such that $x \cdot x = x$, then either $x = 0$ or $x=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck at this proposition:

> Let $x \in\mathbb Z$. If $x \cdot x = x$, then $ x = 0$ or $x = 1$.

Here are the axioms and propositions (I already proved) that I can use:

1. Distributivity
2. Associativity
3. Commutativity
4. Additive inverse
5. Cancellation: Let $m$, $n$, and $p$ be integers. If $m \cdot n = m \cdot p$ and $m \ne\ 0$, then $n = p$
6. Let $m, x_1, x_2 \in\mathbb Z$. If $m, x_1, x_2$ satisfy the equations $m + x_1 = 0$ and $m + x_2 = 0$, then $x_1 = x_2$.
7. Let $x \in\mathbb Z$. If $x$ has the property that for each integer $m$, $m + x = m$, then $x = 0$.
8. For all $m \in\mathbb Z$, $m \cdot 0 = 0 = 0 \cdot m$
9. If $m$ and $n$ are even integers, then so are $m + n$ and $mn$.
10. $0$ is divisible by every integer.
11. If $m$ is not an integer equal to $0$, then $m$ is not divisible by $0$.
12. Let $x \in\mathbb Z$. If $x$ has the property that $mx = m$ for all $m \in\mathbb Z$, then $x = 1$.
13. For all $m,n \in\mathbb Z$, $(-m)(-n) = mn$
14. For all $m \in\mathbb Z$, $-(-m) = m$

Okay, based on the comments below, here is my proof. It has two cases:

- **Case 1:** $x \in\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$. According to (5), $x = 1$.
- **Case 2:** $x = 0$. According to (8), $0 \cdot 0 = 0(x)$.

What do you think?

Comment: $$x^2=x\cdot x=x\iff x(x-1)=0$$

Comment: Well, the cancellation thing (5)  finishes it all! If $\;x^2=x\;$ then $\;x=0\;$ is surely a solution, and if $\;x\neq 0\;$ then *cancel* $\;x\;$ at both sides and get $\;x=1\;$ ...!

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks a lot! It was so obvious! lol I can use 5) to account for all integers except 0 (gives me x =1). Then use 8) to test for zero: any integer multiplied by 0 equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

If $xx=x$ then $x(x-1)=xx-x=0$. The only way for a product of integers to be zero is that at least one of them be zero, so from $x(x-1)=0$ we see that one of $x$ or $x-1$ is zero, that is, that $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input. However, I forgot to mention that I am only allowed to use axioms for addition and multiplication. Technically, I have not looked at subtraction yet.

Comment: Surely you have the existence of additive inverses among your axioms and, as you know, $x-y$ is just a shorthand for $x+(-y)$.

Comment: If you have limitations on what properties of integers and their operations you can use, then you **should** list them quite explicitly in the question body, for it is rather impossible for anyone to guess exactly which those limitations are...

Comment: Thank you! I have added the axioms and propositions.

Comment: x - y is defined later in the exercises, so I can't use it right now. :)

Comment: Well, you apparently can use $x+(-y)$, so use that!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the ring of integers $\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain. So $\mathbb Z$ does not contain any zero divisors. Thus $x.x=x\implies x.(x-1)=0\implies x=0 $ or $(x-1)=0$ i.e. $x=1$.